# Spring: @Value vs. @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-annotations

I'm having some issues with injection in the application I'm working on (using Spring Version 3.1.2). To start with, I'm seeing a lot of code like this:

```
@Value("#{searchRequestBean}")
private SearchRequest searchRequest;

@Value("#{searchResponseBean}")
private SearchResponse searchResponse;

@Autowired
private SavedSearchService service;
```

Each of these three appears to have the effect of autowiring the specified bean/service into the class. What I don't understand is, what's the difference between `@Value` and `@Autowired` in these cases? Every example I find online seems to use `@Value` to inject values from a properties file. In this case, `SearchResponse` and `SearchRequest` are abstract classes.

I'm hoping that a better understanding of this will help me solve some issues I'm having with my Session bean.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`@Value` can be used for injecting default values.  A good example is to inject the default of a `String` to be the value of a property file.  In your example, `@Value` is used to set the default value of a class to be a Spring managed bean.

`@Autowired` can't be used for the first example: It's not property file aware.  `@Autowired` is *only* for DI of a bean.  It is more specific than `@Value`, but you can use `@Value` to do the same thing.

Here is a good tutorial for `@Value`: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/

Comment: thanks for the clear, concise response! My real issue is that I'm seeing the wrong Session bean accessed from my class - we're still working to find the cause. Sounds like the use `@Value` instead of `@Autowired` isn't the cause, although we're thinking it's a Spring issue.

Comment: If I understand the syntax correctly in the particular case, no default value was configured. I think, the difference in the examples is only, that the `@Value` references a bean name and `@Autowired` not. I think `@Autowired  @Qualifier("searchRequestBean")` would do the same as the corresponding `@Value`.