# Why AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor support @Value?

Tags: java, spring

For automatic injection, `@Autowired` is enough, why use `@Value`. I think it maybe ambiguous and semantic inconsistency.
see [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html).

I have to emphasize that the function of `@Autowired` and `@Value` is equivalent for `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. Refer to the following code, They all implement injection functions.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Autowired.class);
    this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Value.class);
    try {
        this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add((Class<? extends Annotation>)
                ClassUtils.forName("javax.inject.Inject", AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class.getClassLoader()));
        logger.info("JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // JSR-330 API not available - simply skip.
    }
}
```

the placeholder function for `@Value` is supported by `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` other than `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551761/spring-value-vs-autowired ?

Comment: @Jayesh Obviously not repeated, the link explain the difference between value and autowired, but my question is focus on AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, For AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, the functions of Autowired and Value are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> **@Autowired** is a spring propriety annotation that inject a resource **by type**, i.e. by corresponding implemented class (annotated with @Component) to afield  annotated with @Autowired. Fundamentally,
>   @Autowired is about type-driven injection.

```
@Autowired
private OrderService orderService;
```

while,

> **@Value** annotation is used to assign a **value** to a property. It is only used to assign a value for a simple type property,for example,
>   primitive types, in a bean class.in this way, IOC container reads the
>   value of a **key** from **resource bundle** and initializes a simple
>   property with that value.

```
@Value("#{mysql.databaseName}")
private String databaseName;
```

In reference to the the above definitions, the difference is clear as you can not assign simple type values using @Autowire. similarly, you also can not inject a complex type (i.e. class) by @Value **so the usages are not the same**

Comment: You have no problem, but it is not the answer I asked.